# How to get a custom product attribute to display in the Woocommerce Additional Information tab table

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I 'm using [Add custom dimension fields to each variation settings for variable products](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45176566/11987538) answer code in order to develop a product "actual" length, width, and height per variation since I need values for the compact shipping dimensions but also customer reference to the product size. Why Woo doesn't offer this by default after years of outcry is beyond me. I have altered the code given for my own purposes:

```
// Add variation custom "dimensions" fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_options_dimensions','add_variation_options_actual_dimensions', 10, 3 );
function add_variation_options_actual_dimensions( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ){

    $variation_actual_length = get_post_meta($variation->ID,"_actual_length", true );
    if( ! $variation_actual_length ) $variation_actual_length = "";

    $variation_actual_width = get_post_meta($variation->ID,"_actual_width", true );
    if( ! $variation_actual_width ) $variation_actual_width = "";

    $variation_actual_height = get_post_meta($variation->ID,"_actual_height", true );
    if( ! $variation_actual_height ) $variation_actual_height = "";

    ?>
    <p class="form-field form-row dimensions_field actual_dimensions hide_if_variation_virtual form-row-last">

        <label for="product_actual_length"><?php
            // translators: %s: dimension unit
            printf(
                __( 'Actual dimensions (L&times;W&times;H) (%s)', 'woocommerce' ),
                get_option( 'woocommerce_dimension_unit' )
            );
        ?></label>

        <?php echo wc_help_tip( __( 'Actual length x width x height in inches decimal form', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?>
        <span class="wrap">

            <input id="product_actual_length" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Actual length', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" class="input-text wc_input_decimal" size="6" type="text" name="actual_length_<?php echo $loop; ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $variation_actual_length ); ?>" />

            <input placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Actual width', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" class="input-text wc_input_decimal" size="6" type="text" name="actual_width_<?php echo $loop; ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $variation_actual_width ); ?>" />

            <input placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Actual height', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" class="input-text wc_input_decimal last" size="6" type="text" name="actual_height_<?php echo $loop; ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $variation_actual_height ); ?>" />

        </span>

    </p>
    <?php

}



    //Save variation custom "dimensions" fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation','save_variation_options_actual_dimensions', 10 ,2 );
function save_variation_options_actual_dimensions( $variation_id, $loop ){

    $actual_length = $_POST["actual_length_$loop"];
    if(!empty($actual_length))
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_actual_length', sanitize_text_field($actual_length) );

    $actual_width = $_POST["actual_width_$loop"];
    if(!empty($actual_width))
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_actual_width', sanitize_text_field($actual_width) );

    $actual_height = $_POST["actual_height_$loop"];
    if(!empty($actual_height))
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_actual_height', sanitize_text_field($actual_height) );
}
```

I have added the product-attributes.php file to my child theme under the [child theme name]/woocommerce/single-product file path.

I have researched and unsuccessfully fiddled with the php for hours to try and get a working code to display these three attributes within the "Additional Information" tab just under the other dimensions readings (preferably inline like Woocommerce does with the shipping dimensions by default). I also want to alter the "Dimensions" wording to be, "Shipping Dimensions" or even get rid of that row entirely. Any useful solution to this would be very much appreciated.

Here is an illustration of what I want to do:

[image]

Also, a wonderful bonus would be an alteration of this code that would let me type in the "actual" length, width, and height in custom fields in the shipping tab for the product and then let me overwrite it by choice in fields in each variation (like Woocomemrce does for the shipping dimensions fields that they offer by default). But I can sense the complication in such a coding so this is just a bonus ask; the code that I posted works as is for my basic needs.

Update: So I have gotten this far on the issue with the coding:

```
// Add variation custom "dimensions" fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_options_dimensions','add_variation_options_actual_dimensions', 10, 3 );
function add_variation_options_actual_dimensions( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ){

    $variation_actual_length = get_post_meta($variation->ID,"_actual_length", true );
    if( ! $variation_actual_length ) $variation_actual_length = "";

    $variation_actual_width = get_post_meta($variation->ID,"_actual_width", true );
    if( ! $variation_actual_width ) $variation_actual_width = "";

    $variation_actual_height = get_post_meta($variation->ID,"_actual_height", true );
    if( ! $variation_actual_height ) $variation_actual_height = "";

    ?>
    <p class="form-field form-row dimensions_field actual_dimensions hide_if_variation_virtual form-row-last">

        <label for="product_actual_length"><?php
            // translators: %s: dimension unit
            printf(
                __( 'Actual dimensions (L&times;W&times;H) (%s)', 'woocommerce' ),
                get_option( 'woocommerce_dimension_unit' )
            );
        ?></label>

        <?php echo wc_help_tip( __( 'Actual length x width x height in inches decimal form', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?>
        <span class="wrap">

            <input id="product_actual_length" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Actual length', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" class="input-text wc_input_decimal" size="6" type="text" name="actual_length_<?php echo $loop; ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $variation_actual_length ); ?>" />

            <input placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Actual width', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" class="input-text wc_input_decimal" size="6" type="text" name="actual_width_<?php echo $loop; ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $variation_actual_width ); ?>" />

            <input placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Actual height', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" class="input-text wc_input_decimal last" size="6" type="text" name="actual_height_<?php echo $loop; ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $variation_actual_height ); ?>" />

        </span>

    </p>
    <?php

}



    //Save variation custom "dimensions" fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation','save_variation_options_actual_dimensions', 10 ,2 );
function save_variation_options_actual_dimensions( $variation_id, $loop ){

    $actual_length = $_POST["actual_length_$loop"];
    if(!empty($actual_length))
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_actual_length', sanitize_text_field($actual_length) );

    $actual_width = $_POST["actual_width_$loop"];
    if(!empty($actual_width))
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_actual_width', sanitize_text_field($actual_width) );

    $actual_height = $_POST["actual_height_$loop"];
    if(!empty($actual_height))
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_actual_height', sanitize_text_field($actual_height) );
}

//Hide shipping dimensions from single product pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_width', 'hide_single_product_dimentions', 25, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_height', 'hide_single_product_dimentions', 25, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_length', 'hide_single_product_dimentions', 25, 2 );
function hide_single_product_dimentions( $value, $product ){
    // Only on single product pages
    if( is_product() )
        $value = '';

    return $value;
}

//Display table values for actual dimensions on single product pages
    
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_additional_information', 'custom_data_in_product_add_info_tab', 20, 1 );
function custom_data_in_product_add_info_tab( $product ) {

    //Product ID - WooCommerce compatibility
    $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;

    // Get your custom fields data
    $actual_length_display = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_actual_lenght', true );
    $actual_width_display = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_actual_width', true );
    $actual_height_display = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_actual_height', true );

    // Set your custom fields labels (or names)
    $label1 = __( 'Actual length', 'woocommerce');
    $label2 = __( 'Actual width', 'woocommerce');
    $label3 = __( 'Actual height', 'woocommerce');
    // The Output
echo'<table class="woocommerce-product-attributes shop_attributes">
<tbody>
            <tr class="custom-field1">
                <th>'. $label1 .'</th>
                <td>'. $actual_length_display .'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="custom-field2">
                <th>'. $label2 .'</th>
                <td>'. $actual_width_display .'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="custom-field3">
                <th>'. $label3 .'</th>
                <td>'. $actual_height_display .'</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>';
 }
```

But, for some reason, the values do not fill in on the "Additional Information" table and I cannot figure out why. Any helpo would be much appreciated. Here is a picture of what I am talking about where I have clearly saved values for this variation which do not show on the front end:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mcUi.png)

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it to a satisfactory level for me but still not what I hoped to get in the end (the mechanics and appearance could be better).

I used the [Custom Woocommerce product variations attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610042/custom-woocommerce-product-variations-attributes) answer code and adjusted it to my purposes as follows:

```
/**
 * Add custom fields to product variation settings
 *
 * @param string $loop
 * @param array $variation_data
 * @param WP_Post $variation
 * @return array
 */
function add_variation_options_other_dimensions( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ){

    $variation_obj = wc_get_product( $variation->ID );

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id' => 'real_length[' . $loop . ']',
        'class' => 'short',
        'label'       => __( 'Actual Length', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => 'L',
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'Product actual length (in inches).', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'       => $variation_obj->get_meta( 'real_length', true ),
    ) );

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id' => 'real_width[' . $loop . ']',
        'class' => 'short',
        'label'       => __( 'Actual Width', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => 'W',
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'Product actual width (in inches).', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'       => $variation_obj->get_meta( 'real_width', true ),
    ) );

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id' => 'real_height[' . $loop . ']',
        'class' => 'short',
        'label'       => __( 'Actual Height', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => 'H',
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'Product actual height (in inches).', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'       => $variation_obj->get_meta( 'real_height', true ),
    ) );

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_options_dimensions','add_variation_options_other_dimensions', 10, 3 );


/**
 * Save product variation custom fields values
 *
 * @param int $variation_id
 * @param int $i
 */
function save_variation_options_other_dimensions( $variation_id, $i ) {

    $variation_obj = wc_get_product( $variation_id );

    if ( isset( $_POST["real_length"][$i] ) ) {
        $variation_obj->update_meta_data( 'real_length', wc_clean( $_POST["real_length"][$i] ) );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST["real_width"][$i] ) ) {
        $variation_obj->update_meta_data( 'real_width', wc_clean( $_POST["real_width"][$i] ) );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST["real_height"][$i] ) ) {
        $variation_obj->update_meta_data( 'real_height', wc_clean( $_POST["real_height"][$i] ) );
    }

    $variation_obj->save();

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation','save_variation_options_other_dimensions', 10 ,2 );

/**
 * Add data to json encoded variation form.
 *
 * @param  array $data - this is the variation's json data
 * @param  object $product
 * @param  object $variation
 * @return array
 */
function kia_available_variation( $data, $product, $variation ){
    $kia_data['real_length']  = $variation->get_meta( 'real_length', true );
    $kia_data['real_width'] = $variation->get_meta( 'real_width', true );
    $kia_data['real_height'] = $variation->get_meta( 'real_height', true );

    return array_merge( $data, $kia_data );

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'kia_available_variation', 10, 3 );


/**
 * Add scripts to variable products.
 */
function kia_on_found_template_for_variable_add_to_cart() {
    add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', 'kia_variable_footer_scripts', 99 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'kia_on_found_template_for_variable_add_to_cart', 30 );


function kia_variable_footer_scripts() { ?>

    <script type="text/template" id="tmpl-variation-template-extra-data">
        <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--attribute_real_length extra-data">
            <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label"><?php esc_html_e( 'Length (in)', 'my-text-domain' );?></th>
            <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value">{{{ data.variation.real_length }}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--attribute_real_width extra-data">
            <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label"><?php esc_html_e( 'Width (in)', 'my-text-domain' );?></th>
            <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value">{{{ data.variation.real_width }}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--attribute_real_height extra-data">
            <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label"><?php esc_html_e( 'Height (in)', 'my-text-domain' );?></th>
            <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value">{{{ data.variation.real_height }}}</td>
        </tr>
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
            $('form.cart')
                .on('found_variation', function( event, variation ) {

                    template     = wp.template( 'variation-template-extra-data' );

                    $template_html = template( {
                        variation: variation
                    } );

                    // Remove any existing rows.
                    $('#tab-additional_information').find('.woocommerce-product-attributes tr.extra-data').remove();
                    // Add new rows.
                    $('#tab-additional_information').find('.woocommerce-product-attributes tbody').append( $template_html );

                })
                .on( 'reset_data', function( event, variation ) {
                    $('#tab-additional_information').find('.woocommerce-product-attributes tr.extra-data').remove();
                });
        });
    </script>
<?php

}
```

I combined that with the answer code from [Remove product dimensions from single product pages in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52199913/remove-product-dimensions-from-single-product-pages-in-woocommerce?rq=1) in order to hide the shipping dimensions in the table:

```
//Hide shipping dimensions from single product pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_width', 'hide_single_product_dimentions', 25, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_height', 'hide_single_product_dimentions', 25, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_length', 'hide_single_product_dimentions', 25, 2 );
function hide_single_product_dimentions( $value, $product ){
    // Only on single product pages
    if( is_product() )
        $value = '';

    return $value;
}
```

The outcome is a functional solution that appears on the back end like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiHVM.png)

And on the front end like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ4ve.png)

If anyone can provide a better code that allows me to display all three dimensions on one line or if anyone can provide code to make the input boxes on the back-end aligned with the original shipping L x W x H boxes then that would be over-the-top wonderful.